# How can I get stack trace information on a device in CodenameOne?

Tags: exception, codenameone, throwable

My app works great in the simulator, great on an Android phone, yet on an Apple phone I get an "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 0" error during startup with no explanation. How can I get at the stacktrace to debug?

This is a great start (from https://www.codenameone.com/blog/handling-the-exception.html)

```
Display.getInstance().addEdtErrorHandler(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    evt.consume();
    Log.p("Exception in AppName version " +Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppVersion", "Unknown"));
    Log.p("OS " + Display.getInstance().getPlatformName());
    Log.p("Error " + evt.getSource());
    Log.p("Current Form " + Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getName());
    Log.e((Throwable)evt.getSource());
    Log.sendLog();
}});
```

However 1) there's no stack trace and 2) Log.sendLog requires a subscription. I'm a self employed hobbyist who can't afford the subscription at this point in my life. I've tried several avenues that would normally in Java:

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);
   PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
   System.setOut(ps);
```

Alas, there is no System.setOut in CodenameOne. But neato, there's a StackTraceElement[] in Throwable!

```
   for (StackTraceElement ste: throwable.getStackTrace()) {
      container.add(new SpanLabel(ste.toString()));
   }
```

Nope that doesn't compile. StackTraceElement appears in Throwable according to my IDE (probably from Java 8) and from source on github (https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/vm/JavaAPI/src/java/lang/Throwable.java) however the code in the CLDC11.jar does not. Either way, java.lang.StackTraceElement is not part of the CodenameOne distribution and it's not supported. Sure would be handy though (read feature request)!

While it's handy that CodenameOne has a built in error handler that pops up a dialog, the error is useless to the end user as they have no idea what it means and useless to the developer without a stack trace. In my case the error only happens on the device and not in the simulator, so as best I can tell there is no way for me to access a stack trace. Is that correct?

Feature requests: include stack trace in the error handling dialog (even if as an expandable +list) and/or include a way to get at the stack trace from code. As best as I can tell stack traces can only go to stdout. Thanks for reading all this!

Comment: The main problem with adding this to the dialog is that we only implemented Log.e() and the implementation is native so we don't actually have a stack trace as a String. I haven't tried the suggestion from Nick but it might work for you. You can also connect a cable to an iOS device to see the printouts like in Android but you need a Mac with xcode. I heard there are tricks to do this on Windows but that's not something I tried.

Answer (score 2):

Android is easy because you can use logcat but for iOS I usually store a string with debug info in storage and you can setup a button (in toolbar) to display the log either as a popup dialog or probably a new form so that it's easier to read.

```
Storage storage = Storage.getInstance();
String log = (String) storage.readObject("debugLog");
log += "your debug string\n";
storage.writeObject("debugLog", log);
```

or you can use preferences

```
Preferences.set("debugLog", Preferences.get("debugLog", null) + "your debug string" + "\n");
```

Comment: That's a great idea to store a log like that and it's easy enough to store logs of different runs. Easy enough to store the names of those logs as a "directory" and make my own little time based file system. Thank you Nick, though curses that debugging has turned into putting a bunch of print statements again. =)

Answer (score 0):

this hack gets a stack trace as a string

```
class LogCapture extends Log
{   Log oldLog;
    StringWriter myWriter;
    LogCapture() 
    { oldLog = Log.getInstance();
      install(this);  
    }
    protected Writer createWriter() throws IOException 
    {   return(myWriter = new StringWriter());
    }
    public String dispose()
    {
        install(oldLog);
        return(myWriter.toString());
    }
}
```

then

```
    public static String getStackTrace(Throwable t)
{
    LogCapture cap = new LogCapture();
    Log.e(t);
    return cap.dispose();   
}
```